# Hibernate Envers does not recognize Any type

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Hibernate Envers appears not to work with org.hibernate.type.AnyType.
When [@Any](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-any) hibernate annotation is used to describe specific polymorphic mapping use case, auditing with Envers does not work out of the box.
With entity field defined as:

```java
    @Any(
            metaDef = "PartyMetaDef",
            metaColumn = @Column( name = "dest_type" )
    )
    @JoinColumn( name = "dest_id" )
    private Party destination;
```

where Party is abstract class and finally comes in one of two flavors.
Actual party type is decided via PartyMetaDef, and ends up in dest_type (CHAR) column in database.
Actual parent entity id is stored in dest_id (LONG).

Now, for some reason Envers cannot work with this and gives

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Type not supported for auditing: org.hibernate.type.AnyType, on entity MyEntity, property 'destination'.
at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.throwUnsupportedTypeException(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:764) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addValueInFirstPass(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:212) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addValue(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:316) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.internal.metadata.AuditMetadataGenerator.addProperties(AuditMetadataGenerator.java:350) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
```

Hibernate and Envers versions are both 5.4.32.Final

PartyMetaDef is defined as:

```java
@AnyMetaDefs(
        @AnyMetaDef( name= "PartyMetaDef", metaType = "string", idType = "long",
                metaValues = {
                        @MetaValue(value = "C", targetEntity = Contact.class),
                        @MetaValue(value = "W", targetEntity = Warehouse.class)
                }
        )
)
```

Both Contact and Warehouse inherit from Party abstract class.

Comment: What are your versions of hibernate and envers? What does you `PartyMetaDef` actually look like?